# Prevent programs from opening

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I'm writing a batch file that kills background processes, but some processes keep starting back up again. (Using Taskkill) I could loop the taskkill command, but that would use more CPU power than it saves. So is there any command/tool that keeps programs closed after I force closed them?

Comment: Prevent something from starting it.

Comment: You could change the permissions to deny execute permission to the applications in question...

Comment: You could create a WMI event Sink on the process start event that would run code to kill the process that you don't want running. Or better yet do what gronostaj suggested and find wht is restarting the app and kill that. Prefereably with fire...

Comment: Some processes have a watchdog that will restart them ...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what app/process are you trying to kill?

Comment: If the program restarts than that is controlled by some related service running. You need to stop this service.

Comment: You can create a GPO policy to prevent specific exe files to start